# Print string and reactive object in the same line in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Im trying to print text and reactive object in the same line using `print()` and `paste()` but it does not work.

```
# define some credentials
credentials <- data.frame(
  user = c("shiny", "shinymanager"), # mandatory
  password = c("azerty", "12345"), # mandatory
  start = Sys.Date(), # optinal (all others)
  expire = c(NA, "2019-12-31"),
  admin = c(FALSE, TRUE),
  comment = "Simple and secure authentification mechanism 
  for single ‘Shiny’ applications.",
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

library(shiny)
library(shinymanager)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h2("My secure application"),
  uiOutput("auth_output")
)

# Wrap your UI with secure_app
ui <- secure_app(ui)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # call the server part
  # check_credentials returns a function to authenticate users
  res_auth <- secure_server(
    check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials)
  )
  
  output$auth_output <- renderText({
    print(paste0(h4("Name:"),h4(res_auth$user)))
          
  })
  
  # your classic server logic
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What jumps out to me is `renderText` is usually paired with `verbatimTextOutput`. If you want to use `uiOutput` you should pair it with `renderUI` in the server code.

That being said, if you are expecting it to display an h4 heading in the UI, you won't get what you expect. `h4` returns a `shiny.tag` object. `paste0` will coerce these to characters. You more likely want to create your text then use it to create the h4.

```
output$auth_output <- renderUI({
    h4(paste0("Name:", res_auth$user))
})
```